# Converting Object to Dataframe and it is giving me Value, Name, and dtype in each cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

- I am running a for loop off a regression per item within a multi-item dataset.
- I want to output to give me the price point at the max revenue point of the parameters set in the `np.arrange`.
- Here is the code I am working with:

```
upc_modelfit_summary = []
upcs = df['upc'].unique()

for x in upcs:
    
    df_upc = df[(df['upc'] == x)]     
    max_val = df_upc['arp_np'].max()
    min_val = df_upc['arp_np'].min()
    price = np.arange(min_val, max_val, 0.1)
    cost = .50
    model = ols("units_np ~ arp_np", data=df_upc).fit()
    quantity = []
    revenue = []
    
    for i in price:
     demand = model.params[0] + (model.params[1] * i)
     quantity.append(demand)
     revenue.append((i-cost) * demand)
    profit = pd.DataFrame({"Price": price, "Revenue": revenue, "Quantity": quantity, "UPC": x})
    max_val = profit.loc[(profit['Revenue'] == profit['Revenue'].max())]
    upc_modelfit_summary.append(
        {
            'Price': max_val['Price'],
            'Revenue': max_val['Revenue'],
            'Quantity': max_val['Quantity'],
            'UPC': max_val['UPC']
        })

a= pd.DataFrame(upc_modelfit_summary)
a
```

I would like to create a dataframe that compiles the price, revenue, quantity, and upc for each item that is looped.

For some reason when converting this to a dataframe it is giving me the values, names, and dtypes of each cell value (see image)

Is there a better way to do this? Ideally the end result would be a df that could be exported in some fashion.

```
Price   Revenue Quantity    UPC
0   4 4.49 Name: Price, dtype: float64  4 3.99 Name: Revenue, dtype: float64    4 1.0 Name: Quantity, dtype: float64    4 00-28400-04330 Name: UPC, dtype: object
```

[image]

Comment: `max_val` at the end of the iteration (you defined it twice, not sure if that was your intention...) is a DataFrame. So `upc_modelfit_summary` is a list of DataFrames, thus making `a` a DataFrame of DataFrames. What you see in the screen is not the actual data but just a oneliner representation of it.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't mean to define it twice. Are you saying I should define `upc_modelfit_summary`  before the for-loop as `upc_modelfit_summary = pd.DataFrame()` and then append to it using the code you provided?

Comment: Also getting a `KeyError: 0` when I try using the code you provided below :(

Comment: @RyanMcConnell, I've edited the code to fix the issue.

Comment: @MarceloPaco still getting an index error with that, unfortunately.. ```IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0```

Comment: I tried converting the max.val to a numpy array and then appending the arrays into a list. From there I tried to make a dataframe but received an error

```max_val = profit.loc[(profit['Revenue'] == profit['Revenue'].max())]   
max_val = max_val.values   
upc_modelfit_summary.append(max_val)

df = pd.DataFrame(upc_modelfit_summary,columns=['Price', 'Revenue', 'Quantity','UPC'])```

Comment: @RyanMcConnell, third time the charm. I've edited the code once again.

Comment: @MarceloPaco I did. I don't have 15 reputations yet but it says my upvote has been recorded. Thanks!

Comment: All good, have a grep day/night! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're adding the entire data-frame `max_val[Col]` into the `upc_modelfit_summary` dictionary instead of just the value. Change the  `upc_modelfit_summary.append()` line to this:

```
 upc_modelfit_summary.append(
    {
        'Price': max_val['Price'].values[0] if max_val['Price'].values.size > 0 else np.nan,
        'Revenue': max_val['Revenue'].values[0] if max_val['Revenue'].values.size > 0 else np.nan,
        'Quantity': max_val['Quantity'].values[0] if max_val['Quantity'].values.size > 0 else np.nan,
        'UPC': max_val['UPC'].values[0] if max_val['UPC'].values.size > 0 else np.nan
    })
```